# pygame wall collision is ignored

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Hi I am attempting to make a platformer where the edges of the screen act as walls. However, the problem is that the player goes through the wall. Here is the function that checks for walls:

```
def check_walls(self):
    if self.rect.right >= WIDTH:
        self.speedx = 0.5
    if self.rect.left >= WIDTH - WIDTH:
        self.speedx = -0.5
```

And here is the code that makes the player move, I think this is the piece of code that is actually causing the problem but I don't know how to fix it:

```
def update(self):
    self.speedx = 0
    # The speedy is above in the __init__ for the player jumping movement
    self.onGround = True

    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if self.rect.y <= GROUND - BLOCK_DIM:
        self.speedy += self.gravity
        self.onGround = False
    elif self.rect.y >= GROUND - BLOCK_DIM:
        self.speedy = 0
        self.onGround = True


    if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.speedx = -5
    if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.speedx = 5
    if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.jump()
    self.rect.x += self.speedx
    self.rect.y += self.speedy
```

Is there a better method to check for collisions between the player and the wall, take in mind that the walls are just the screen borders not sprites.
Also the check_walls() is called in the **init** which is not added here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do:

```
def check_walls(self):
    if self.rect.right >= WIDTH:
        self.speedx = -0.5
    if self.rect.left <= 0:
        self.speedx = 0.5
```

also where do you call check_walls?

Comment: The check_walls is in the init

Comment: by init you mean the class __init__? you should probably call check_walls every animation frame, not just once at the start.

Comment: I put it inside the update and it now works. Thanks a lot!